# Excel sheet to SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, excel, wcf

I get the Excel sheet with data uploaded from UI, I need to access that sheet through WCF service and insert the data contained in it into a SQL table.

Kindly guide how this can be done.

I am facing challenge in reading that Excel sheet through WCF service.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *SQL database* - **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know *what concrete database system* (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly - use `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, `mysql`, `postgresql` or whatever else you might be using)

Comment: Do You have excel file on cilent side or server side?

Comment: @blogprogramisty.net  I have excel file on client side

Answer (score 1):

I have used below code to read a Excel sheet from a local drive. Change Source property to your FTP location of your excel sheet.

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\MyData.xlsx;" +
                      @"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);
            using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    // Do your things here
                }
            }
        }
```

Note: .xls has data limitations whereas .xlsx supports more data rows in a sheet. You need to install Microsoft Office Access database engine 2007 if you are going to read .xlsx files

Answer (score 0):

```
        string UploadedFilePath = FullPathOfExcelOnTheServer;
        string ExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + UploadedFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;FMT=Delimited\"";
        using (OleDbConnection oledbConnExcel = new OleDbConnection(ExcelConn))
        {

            oledbConnExcel.Open();
            using (OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapterExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from [" + SheetName + "$]", oledbConnExcel))
            {
                using (DataTable dtblSheetData = new DataTable())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        oledbAdapterExcel.Fill(dtblSheetData);
                    }
                    catch (Exception lexQuery)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            oledbConnExcel.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fact is the is no way to read the excel data through WCF Service. But You can cosider this approaches

You may:

1. Read all excel data on client side and call WCF service and include all data from excel in parameter as (array of strings)?
2. You can create macro(VB) in Excel sheet and what call WCF Service and send data through parameter. When You have all logic in one place.
3. If client side is .NET side You can use atribbute `[KnowsTypeAtribbute]`.Then You can call WCF service with param type as Excel type (Sheet or other). May by use some type form OpenXml dll may by usefull (But I don't know is sheet or other types is serializable. A serializable is require)
4. You can send to WFC service path to file and read excel file from that path through WCF service.